# Property of the characteristic function

Tags: real-analysis, characteristic-functions

Hello is the first time I encounter the characteristic function 
$\chi_A(x)=1$ for $x\in A$ and $\chi_A(x)=0$ for $x\notin A$.
I have proved some of the properties of $\chi_A(x)$ but I'm struggling
to proof that
$$\chi_{[x,a]}(y)=\chi_{[0,y]}(x)$$
where $a$ is a constant and $0 \leq  x \leq y \leq a$.

Comment: There is not enough information to prove what you need. Check if you are not missing conditions such as $0 \le x \le y \le a$.

Comment: My bad, I certainly forgot to include those conditions in my question, I will edit my question

Answer (score 0):

You have enough information now to compute each value directly!

What is $\chi_{[x, a]}(y)$? HINT: by assumption $x\le a\le y$, so what do you know about $y$ and the set $[x, a]$?

Similarly, what is $\chi_{[0, y]}(x)$? HINT: by assumption, $0\le x\le y$. . .